Symfony Validator does not work with nested AtLeastOneOf Constraint
In following code (condensed from a project) the validation for $constraint2 returns no error, which is not the behaviour I expect (should also return errors):
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\AtLeastOneOf;
    
    $config = 1; //Integer
    $constraint1 = new AtLeastOneOf([ new Type('string') ]);
    $constraint2 = new AtLeastOneOf([ new AtLeastOneOf([ new Type('string') ]) ]);
    
    $validator = Validation::createValidator();
    echo "Constraint 1: ".(count($validator->validate($config,$constraint1))).'<br>';
    echo "Constraint 2: ".(count($validator->validate($config,$constraint2))).'<br>';

Output:
Constraint 1: 1
Constraint 2: 0

The problem seems to be the nested AtLeastOneOf validator, but I do not understand why it does validate to no errors.

I don't get why you are trying to nest multiple AtLeastOneOf constraint ? Why are you not doing AtLeastOneOf[string, int] instead of: AtLeastOneOf[AtLeastOneOf[string], AtLeastOneOf[[int]]

As I said this is simplified code to demonstrate the problem, in reality the code validates against a deeply nested array. An in this hierarchy a nested AtLeastOneOf() occurs, which does not validate as I would expect it.

This behavior was indeed not expected, so I looked into it.
As of today, it seems that there is an issue with nested AtLeastOneOf constraint as you can see from this issue from symfony/symfony.
You probably do not want to wait for a fix so maybe the only way to fix it now is to
Replace your deeply nested AtLeastOneOf constraint
Let's say your constraint is:
    $constraints = [
        new AtLeastOneOf(
            [
                new Type('string'),
                new Type('datetime'),
                new AtLeastOneOf([ new Type('boolean'), new Type('string') ]),
            ])
    ];

You should be able to replace it with an equivalent constraint:
    $constraints = [
        new AtLeastOneOf(
            [
                new Type('string'),
                new Type('datetime'),
                new Type('boolean'),
                new Type('string'),
            ])
    ];

If two AtLeastOneOf constraint are nested, you should be able to put whatever is in the second one into the first one without changing its behavior.

Thanks for finding the error report. I tested this with a range of Symfony-Versions. Strange that the bug report ist just from April.
Sadly the restructuring works for the simplified version, in my code this is too deeply nested and does not work. Hope they will fix this error.
